# React useState not updating because of useRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state, use-ref

I am experiencing a very odd issue with my react code : useState isn't updating the view and after literally trying everything the issue is still there. I made a simple code to explain the issue :

```js
function(){
  
    const [enterJob, setEnterJob] = useState(false);
    const [jobSelection, setJobSelection] = useState(Array(someList.length).fill(false));
    const jobRef = useRef();

    const handleJobClick = i => {
        const n = parseInt(i.target.id.charAt(0)); // the list is small enough to allow this
        let c = jobSelection;
        c[n] = !c[n];
        setJobSelection(c);
    };
  
  
  const handleMouse = (e) =>{
        if (!jobRef.current.contains(e.target)){
            setEnterJob(false);
        };
    };
  
  useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouse);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("mousedown", handleMouse);
    });
  return(
        <div ref={jobRef}>
           <input onFocus={()=> setEnterJob(true)} />
           <div style={{display: `${enterJob ? 'flex' : 'none'}`}} >
               <ul>
                { someList.map((item,index)=> 
                <li id={`${index}`} onClick={handleJobClick}> {jobSelection[index] ? item : "you clicked on the button"} </li> )}
               </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
  
  )


}
```

Some explanations: I am using UseEffect and useRef to create a dropDown menu that disappears when you clic outside the container. Now when I want to clic on a value of this drop-down menu it doesn't update the DOM while I am using useState to update the value of the string responsible for the change.

Thank you in advance,
Charbel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutatiing your `jobSelection` instead of creating a new object. And react will skip the rerender if the the objects has the same reference as before:

```
 const handleJobClick = i => {
        const n = parseInt(i.target.id.charAt(0)); // the list is small enough to allow this
        let c = [...jobSelection]; // Create a new array
        c[n] = !c[n];
        setJobSelection(c);
    };
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much that was it ! I will need to learn a bit more about mutations.

Answer (score 1):

## Issues

If I understand your issue then I believe it is because you are directly mutating your state.

```
const handleJobClick = i => {
    const n = parseInt(i.target.id.charAt(0)); // the list is small enough to allow this
    let c = jobSelection;
    c[n] = !c[n]; // <-- mutation!
    setJobSelection(c);
};
```

You are also missing react keys on the mapped list items.

## Solution

Since the next state depends on the previous state you should use a functional state update to copy your state first, *then* update it.

I suggest:

1. converting `handleJobClick` to consume the index directly, a curried function handles this cleanly
2. Add a react key to the mapped list items

Code

```
const handleJobClick = index => () => {
  setJobSelection(jobSelection => jobSelection.map(
    (selection, i) => index === i ? !selection : selection // <-- toggle selection at matched index
  );
};

...

<ul>
  {someList.map((item, index)=> (
    <li
     key={index} // <-- index as react key, ok since not adding/removing/sorting jobs
     onClick={handleJobClick(index)} // <-- pass index to handler
    >
      {jobSelection[index] ? item : "you clicked on the button"}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you very much that was it. @Domino987 's  solution is a bit simpler but this one is much more easy to understand.

Comment: No problem, the same goes for objects, arrays and even strings and booleans. If you ahve any questions, hit me up

Comment: @CharbelImad Sure thing. I noticed a couple other issues so I updated my answer to help address them.

Comment: Thank you for this correction. I have a weird issue when passing the index value this way @drew-reese : I get an infinite loop render error. I am going to look more closely and will get back to you.

Comment: @CharbelImad Did you change the `handleJobClick` function signature? `handleJobClick = index => () => {...}`? It's a curried function to take an index and return a function to use as the callback, i.e. it accepts the event but since we don't care about *anything* in the event object we don't need to assign it an identifier.

Comment: Yup, it's the same function. It's weird I must admit.

Comment: @CharbelImad If there is still the issue if you can create a running codesandbox with the issue I can help debug.

Comment: @DrewReese it looks like it is gone for now. Thank you once more for all !